# Why google maps for rails gem creating location with nil longtitude?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have such problem. I'm using google_maps_for_rails gem and it is can't find location correctly. I run all instructions from documentation.

Here is my application.erb:

```
<%= yield :scripts%>
```

My model:

```
attr_accessible :address, :latitude, :longtitude

acts_as_gmappable

def gmaps4rails_address 
  self.address
end
```

but when I create location I get object with nil longtitude. Here is log:

```
   INSERT INTO "locations" ("address", "created_at", "latitude", "longtitude", "name", 
"updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["address", "Lviv"], ["created_at", Thu, 07 
Feb 2013 10:56:45 UTC +00:00], ["latitude", 49.839683], ["longtitude", nil], ["name",
 nil], ["updated_at", Thu, 07 Feb 2013 10:56:45 UTC +00:00]]
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your code:

```
attr_accessible :address, :latitude, :longtitude
```

Typo: `longtitude`

Note that you can personalize the fields [according to my doc](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Model-Customization):

```
acts_as_gmappable :lat => "latitude", :lng => "longtitude"
```